# File importing in python

Tags: python

```
   1. from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField
   2. from wtforms.validators import (DataRequired, Regexp, Email, ValidationError)
```

The first line probably means (correct me if I am wrong) that there is a file name wtforms.py having classes StringField and PasswordField defined in it.
But I am unable to understand what does the second line means. Does it mean that there is a folder name 'wtforms' having validators.py in it that has classes like DataRequired, Regexp and all? If yes, how does python interpreter differentiates between a 'wtform' folder and a 'wtform.py' file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first assumption is not correct. There might be a file called `wtforms.py`, but it could be a `.pyd` file written in C, or it could be a *package* - a directory or "folder".

In the case of a package (directory) it will execute a file called `__init__.py` in the directory itself (there are exceptions to this allowed in Python 3).

Again, in the second assumption, there *might* be a file called `validators.py` in the `wtforms` directory, but again it could be a compiled `.pyd` file, or even a sub-directory.  Large directory hierarchies are possible, you cannot make assumptions.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, cdarke! But I still didn't get my answer yet. This is a valid snippet of code from a Flask project. Can you please explain how the importing is actually happening (in this case)?

Comment: Well, I got my answer! I checked the directories myself. Thanks for everything. :)